# Correlation of all variables in a data.farme in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, correlation

I know inputting a data.frame to `cor` will automatically give a correlation matrix (ex. `cor(mtcars)`).

But I wonder why when I input my own data.frame (`dat_w`) to `cor` I get the below error?

I have `NA` and `Inf` but have used `use = 'pairwise.complete.obs'`.

```
dat_w <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/n/master/w1.csv', stringsAsFactors = F)


cor(dat_w, use = 'pairwise.complete.obs')

# >Error : 'x' must be numeric
```

Comment: Do you want to replace  the NaN, NA  with some other value i.e 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find the columns that are numeric automatically

```
i1 <-  sapply(dat_w, is.numeric)
out <- cor(dat_w[i1], use = 'pairwise.complete.obs')
```

If we want to replace the `NaN` with some value, i.e. 0

```
out1 <-  replace(out, is.nan(out)|is.na(out), 0)
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `nrow(subset(reshape(head(w2), idvar = c('person_id', 'gender'), direction = 'long', varying = list(3:ncol(w2))), person_id == 1)) 
#[1] 35`

Comment: @Reza Have you seen my earlier changed comment `nrow(na.omit(subset(reshape(head(w2), idvar = c('person_id', 'gender'), direction = 'long', varying = list(3:ncol(w2))), person_id == 1)))`

Comment: @Reza You can check `res <- reshape(w2, idvar = c('person_id', 'gender'), direction = 'long', varying = list(3:ncol(w2)))# nrow(na.omit(subset(res, person_id == 1)))#
[1] 31`

Answer (score 0):

Because your 2nd column (`gender`) is not numeric. Try :

```
cor(dat_w[-2], use = 'pairwise.complete.obs')
```

Comment: Thank you! I see a lot of `NaN`,  is it possible to remove them?

Comment: How to remove them? Remove columns with all `NaN` values or remove rows with all `NaN` values or remove them with only single `NaN` value or anything else?